# Accessing Angular/Django Application deployed on EC2 through host computer

Tags: django, angular, networking, amazon-ec2, web-deployment

I have deployed 2 applications on a EC2 machines.
1. Angular 8 Application (frontend) running on 0.0.0.0:80
2. Django Application (backend) running on 127.0.0.1:8000

I am able to access my Angular (frontend) application through browser on http://localhost:80 and also getting successful response from my backend application.

Whenever I am trying to access this application from any other system (present in the same network), I can still access my frontend application on http://public_ip:80, but not getting any response from the backend.

Comment: How the frontend is routed to backend? What happens if you access it from the ec2 with publicIP:80 or primaryIP:80 of the machine. 

You may need to route the traffic from primaryIP:80 to primary:8000

Comment: I have added port 80 i.e. 127.0.0.1:80 (as 0.0.0.0:80 will get resolved into localhost) in CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST in my Django app and which is why my application is working fine from the same machine. But, I suspect that every time I am making a request from another system within the network, the Public IP of that system is not getting resolved into 127.0.0.1:80